# case share records are not visible in caseshare table

Tags: apex, apex-sharing

[image: case sharing pic]

I have added case share using manual share(apex programming) and I could see the id from the case share table in debug logs after insert. I have verified everything including users access(community user) and on the object level for the case but not able to see these case share records in caseshare table.

Please let me know what else can I check?

[image: User and Group Sharing]

Comment: Please share some code .Also some info around how are you querying  case table ?workbench or developer console ?Are you able to view the case as login to that user with whom you shared

Comment: Do you mean you can't see case share records or case records?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. What I wanted to do is to create a caseshare for the case creator. In my code, I didn't specify the Rowcause as recommended. The caseshare is created with an ID according to the Debug Log but on table it doesnt show..Any comment?

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but since this was the top hit on google when I ran into this issue, I guess it is still relevant.

As per [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm#Creating_User_Managed_Sharing_Using_Apex), all manual shares are removed when the owner changes. This also applies when using auto-assignment rules, which seems to be the case in the example.

**Placing the sharing code in an after update trigger solves the issue, as they are run after auto-assignment rules are applied.**

Also, upvote [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqA4) if you think this issue should be solved :)